# "(Invoke-WebRequest -uri "example.com").Content" how does this work? What do the parenthesis and period change?

Tags: powershell, syntax

I'm trying to teach myself PowerShell and cannot find this info. I searched a lot before coming and asking this.

`(Invoke-WebRequest -uri "example.com").Content`

---

This produces the same result, so is the above command simply a cursory way of writing the below?

`Invoke-WebRequest -uri "example.com" | Write-Host`

---

When the command is executed, what does wrapping it in parenthesis followed by ".content" change?

Sorry for the dumb question. I'm simply trying to learn =)

Comment: The [`Write-Host`](https://docs.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host) cmdlet's primary purpose is to produce for-(host)-display-only output, such as printing colored text. **This output should not be used in for further scripting.** The syntax `(Invoke-WebRequest -uri "example.com").Content` is called [member enumeration](https://docs.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays#member-enumeration) and returns a collection of the specific property (or a single property). This output might be used for further processing.

Comment: It's just coincidence that the output looks the same in both cases. With `Write-Host` you depend upon what the developers of the cmdlet decided would be the most useful representation for displaying purposes. This could be anything, in some cases even nothing useful at all (e. g. just the name of the object). When using the property syntax, _you_ decide which part of the object should be printed.